# special character in dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file with the following content

```
id,pos_id,supplier_id
5127973,2000,"test
5704355,77,/10122
```

I wanted to load it into a dataframe and the data as it is , this dataframe will be loaded into postresql through JDBC

Here what I did:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("my app")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(conf = conf).appName("spark session example").getOrCreate()

val df= sparkSession.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true").option("escape", "\"").load("C:\\Users\\MHT\\Desktop\\data.csv")
   df.show()
    +-------+------+--------------------+
    |     id|pos_id|         supplier_id|
    +-------+------+--------------------+
    |5127973|  2000|test
    5704355,77,/...|
    +-------+------+--------------------+
```

What should I do to get the same data in the dataframe and then the same data in postresql.

Comment: First - question is unclear - what is the actual problem - is it that the two lines are read as one line due to the unclosed double quotes? (If so, all the postgresql stuff is just redundant and confusing). Second - which Spark version are you using? I'm using 2.1.1 and seeing different results (CSV parsed correctly as two lines)

Comment: @Tzach Zohar , when i show the dataframe  what i get is different from the real content of the csv file , that's it , how can i get the same i talk about the quote

Comment: And what Spark version are you using?

Comment: @TzachZohar 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Write the csv data on to HDFS and using sqoop we can export the data to the destination database by providing required jdbc jars in the  $SQOOP_HOME/lib directory.

Comment: That is not an answer to this question, author of question wants to do it in Spark, which is possible, so answer should be about Spark